# Probability of events

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Here is a probability problem: you observe .5 cars on average passing in front of you every 5 minutes on a road. What is the probability of seeing at least 1 car in 10 minutes?

I'm trying to solve this in 2 ways. The first way is to say: P(no car in 5 minutes) = 1 - .5 = .5. P(no car in first 5 minutes and no car in second 5 minutes) = P(no car in first 5 minutes) * P(no car in second 5 minutes) by independence. Therefore P(at least 1 car in 10 minutes) = 1 - .5*.5 = .75.

However, if I try the same, with a Poisson distribution with rate lambda = .5 per unit of time, for 2 units of time, I get: P(at least 1 car in 2 units of time) = 1 - exp(-2*lambda) = .63.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, what explains the discrepancy?

Comment: Why do you claim P(no car in 5 minutes) is .5?

Comment: Yes, I guess I should claim instead... E[n observed cars per 5 minutes] = .5. Is that right?

Comment: Yes...well really you are assuming E[n observed cars per 5 minutes] = .5 in order to proceed with your problem.  You really just know the observed rate for the 5 minutes and don't truly know the real E[n observed cars per 5 minutes] though.

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to assume it's a good enough estimation to proceed. I don't know the real one, but I'll take the estimate, assuming I have observed that many times in the past. Does that mean my first calculation is wrong, but the one based on Poisson is correct?

Comment: This sounds like a standard Poisson process question. I would go with your second solution. As @MichaelMcGowan pointed out, observing cars at a rate of $.5$ per $5$ minute period is not necessarily the same as having a $.5$ probability of observing a car within a $5$ minute period.

Comment: The Poisson model works if you are assuming interarrival times are exponetial.  By making an assumption about the time to occurrence you can compute the probability you want as a function of the unknown rate parameter lambda.  I guess in your case you are saying that you have seen the process long enough to estimate lambda very accurately.  So you can assume you know it for purposes of calculating the probabilities. The first way you computed you claimed P(no car in five minutes)=0.5 and you did this without assuming an interrarival distribution.  That makes no sense.

Comment: The result depends on the interarrival distribution and would be one value for exponential and another if you assumed a different gamma distribution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is actually a connection between your two calculations. As the commenters pointed out, the key is in interpreting the statement of "0.5 cars on average every 5 minutes". It could mean that in every 5 minute interval there is either 0 or 1 car passing, with P(1 car)=0.5. In that case your first calculation is correct.

But you could get that average in lots of other ways. For example, if every minute there is ether 0 or 1 car passing, with P(1 car)=0.1, that is there are still 0.5 cars on average every 5 minutes, then a very similar calculation would get you P(at least 1 car in 10 minutes)$=1-0.9^{10} = 0.651$. Note how much closer it is to the Poisson result.

As you divide your 5 minute interval into more and more pieces (say, $k\rightarrow\infty$), and assume that only 0 or 1 car can pass during those $5/k$ minutes with probability $0.5/k$, that is still at 0.5 cars on average during 5 minutes, the probability from the first calculation will be $1 - (1 - 0.5/k)^{2k} \rightarrow 1-e^{-1}=0.632 $, which is the result of the Poisson-based calculation.

In fact, this construction is essentially the definition of a Poisson process. The other properties, like exponential inter-arrival time, are just consequences.